# SQL While Exists Gets stuck in loop?

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I have a cursor that is basically inserting new usernames in a table. I am trying to check for existing ones and append a '_1' or '_2' etc.

However it appears as though my code is getting stuck in a loop and never finishes.

Here is the code in question I belive:

```
        SET @NUM = 1

        --If Username already exists append number
        While Exists ( select Null from CUSTOMTABLE Where USER_PRINCIPAL_NAME = @UPN)

        BEGIN
            SET @UPN = @UPN+'_'+RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(10), @NUM))
            SET @NUM = @NUM+1
        END
```

I then go on to insert the value '@upn' into a table. Am I not doing this while exists correctly?

Comment: That looks like a single statement. Why are you using a `While`? Just use `If Exists`

Comment: I want it to loop and keep increasing until the upn does not exist

Comment: What is the value of @UPN before starting the loop? My guess is it is NULL. Concatentating a NULL with another string returns NULL. So this could get stuck in an infinite loop depending on the null ansi setting.

Comment: It can vary... but it would represent something like  FirstInitial+LastName, so for example it would be 'JSmith'... and if 'JSmith' exists it then should be changed to 'JSmith_1'

Comment: In your  set, replace @UPN with ISNULL(@UPN,'') and let us know if that resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

This should absolutely work. You aren't taking NULL into account and you also are adding *# repeatedly, so your string will start looking like x*#, x_#*#, x*#*#*#, etc.

```
SET @NUM = 1
SET @UPN=ISNULL(@UPN,'')

DECLARE @OrgUPN NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @OrgUPN = @UPN

        --If Username already exists append number
        While Exists ( select Null from CUSTOMTABLE Where USER_PRINCIPAL_NAME = @UPN)

        BEGIN
            SET @UPN = @OrgUPN+'_'+RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(10), @NUM))
            SET @NUM = @NUM+1
        END
```

Comment: It turned out to be the datatype I was using on the @UPN variable. The set was never actually changing the value of UPN.....